# Express Node.js response to AJAX call from client does not send fully

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

im using an ajax get request to get data from the server (a spotify playlist structure, to be displayed for the user. But I'm having some trouble with transmitting. This issue is only prevelent when using the external ip (and not with localhost)

The data being received correctly on localhost:
[image]

with headers:

```
Request URL: http://www.localhost:8080/spotify/ajax/requestSongs
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Content-Length: 821946
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2020 19:18:51 GMT
ETag: W/"c8aba-7NdUbhReuN0XXnw3DPVSyrNAS38"
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3A0yZXFKy7MgsfbY_OX5yanp5HKlvdSGKY.8BaJrUmEGn9z9ohyRTtkXBCTj6wxiDDoaLNFS8vEdl8
Host: www.localhost:8080
If-None-Match: W/"c8aba-7NdUbhReuN0XXnw3DPVSyrNAS38"
Referer: http://www.localhost:8080/spotify/edit?playlist=5LDRNl7lGrxm7mx2RVggVC
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36
```

The data being incorrectly received on external ip:
[image: timing file]

with headers:

```
Request URL: http://86.90.233.152:8080/spotify/ajax/requestSongs
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: MYIP:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 821946
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2020 19:03:00 GMT
ETag: W/"c8aba-7NdUbhReuN0XXnw3DPVSyrNAS38"
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AlGbD5iWpq9sJlLCFvBsj20RkR9_gZrEr.D9rOpXr5M6FfHnUe7DUx0xzLybQhsGsLIuYsys0FrP4
Host: 86.90.233.152:8080
Referer: http://MYIP:8080/spotify/edit?playlist=5LDRNl7lGrxm7mx2RVggVC
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36
```

The ajax response doesn't change after the second XMLhttp reply.
Furthermore, to try and find the issue I log every response coming into ajax and the console is:

```
clientscript.js:8 XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 1, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
clientscript.js:8 XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 2, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
clientscript.js:8 XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 3, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
clientscript.js:8 XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 3, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
```

SOURCE:

Server side replier

```
router.get("/ajax/requestSongs", function(req,res, next)
{
  if(req.session.lastPlaylist)
  {
    localPlaylists[res.locals.sessionId].getSortedGenres((sortedGenres) => localPlaylists[res.locals.sessionId].getPlaylist( (playlist) => 
    {
      var data={sortedGenres : sortedGenres, playlist : playlist}
      console.log(data);
      res.send(data);
    }));
  }

});
```

Client side receiver:

```
function getData(suburl, callback)
{
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //console.log(this.responseText);
        console.log(this)
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
        {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            callback(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", pathPrefix+"/ajax/"+suburl, true);

    xhttp.send();
}
```

An example of how data is cut off (the ....... is correct data):

```
........"art rock","blues rock","classic rock","hard rock","metal","psychedelic rock","rock","soft rock"]},{"artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https://open.s
```

Comment: In your `console.log(data)` right before `res.send(data)`, do you see all the data there?

Comment: Yes, the console.log does not differ between localhost and the external ip. var data is set correct.

Answer (score 0):

Because it only makes a difference when you're on an external link and the data is large (not huge, but not small either), I suspect that there's some sort of problem with the transmission, perhaps some sort of internal buffer overflow problem.  I was under the impression that `res.send()` is supposed to just "handle that for you", but apparently that is not the case.

I would first add an error handler on the output stream and see if it logs anything:

```
router.get("/ajax/requestSongs", function(req, res, next)
{
  if(req.session.lastPlaylist)
  {
    localPlaylists[res.locals.sessionId].getSortedGenres((sortedGenres) => localPlaylists[res.locals.sessionId].getPlaylist( (playlist) => 
    {
      var data={sortedGenres : sortedGenres, playlist : playlist}
      console.log(data);

      // log any errors on the response stream
      res.on('error', function(err) {
         console.log(err);
      });

      res.send(data);
    }));
  }

});
```

Then, my theory of some sort of buffer overflow would suggest that you need to implement flow control upon sending of the data.  I thought `res.send()` was supposed to do that for you, but you can implement it yourself like this and see if it solves the problem:

```
router.get("/ajax/requestSongs", function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.session.lastPlaylist) {
        localPlaylists[res.locals.sessionId].getSortedGenres((sortedGenres) => localPlaylists[res.locals.sessionId].getPlaylist( (playlist) => {
            res.type("application/json");
            res.status(200);

            const data = JSON.stringify({sortedGenres : sortedGenres, playlist : playlist});
            const chunkSize = 1024 * 10;   // send in 10k chunks
            let pos = 0, chunk;

            function sendNextChunk() {
                if (pos < data.length) {
                    chunk = data.substr(pos, chunkSize);
                    pos += chunkSize;
                    let flushed = res.write(chunk);
                    if (!flushed) {
                        // need to wait for drain event before sending more
                        res.once('drain', sendNextChunk);
                    } else {
                        // send more without stack build-up
                        setImmediate(sendNextChunk);
                    }
                } else {
                    // finish the response
                    res.end();
                }
            }

            // log any write errors on the response
            res.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });

            // start the sending sequence
            sendNextChunk();
        }));
    } else {
      // have to send something here when no playlist
        res.send("No previously established playlist");
    }
});
```